# Motor has been serviced in time and a day later the car won't start

Tags: starting, citroen, keyless-entry, citroen-c4

2005 Citroen C4, 1400cc petrol model.

After I changed my key FOB's battery, car was running fine. A day later I unlock the car by using the FOB and then try to start the engine.  It turns over fine but the engine won't start.

Is there an explanation as to why and how this occurring?

Comment: Did is start happening after the key fob battery was changed? Are you sure the key does not have to be reprogrammed after a battery change?

Comment: I made your question readable.  Can you validate that I didn't change the meaning of it by reading my changes and commenting that it looks good?  Thanks.

Comment: Your question title mentions a motor service, but the text seems to be focused on your key fob.  Are you just unsure what caused the trouble?